# Matlab: Make interactive movie from figure

Tags: matlab, animation, interactive, movie

I have developed a GUI in Matlab where the user can pan/rotate a 3D-plot via the camera controls toolbar. Now a customer would like to record the figure/plot while beeing able to interactively change the position.

So far I have tried to put the writeVideo command in a while-loop like this...

```
aviobj = VideoWriter( ['test.avi'] );
open(aviobj);
fig = handles.axes_3DViewer;
stopState=1;
while stopState == 1
  cameratoolbar('SetMode','orbit');
  axis vis3d
  writeVideo(aviobj, getframe(fig));
  pause(0.1);
  stopState=strcmp(get(handles.uipushtool_stop,'State'),'on');
end;
close(aviobj);
```

but when rotating I only get errors like:

```
Error while evaluating uitoggletool ClickedCallback

Error using VideoWriter/writeVideo (line 383)
Frame must be 553 by 650
```

I have tried so set a frame for the  writeVideo command but somehow it didn't change the outcome. Anyone has some ideas how to this in Matlab?

Cheers 
Mika

Comment: Just to be clear: you would like to capture the figure's content continuously as the user modifies it?

Comment: When rotating or operating on `axes` (zooming, panning etc ...), it is common for Matlab to automatically change the `axes` size to accommodate for updated ticks or other axes extradata. The change in size is often minimal for the eye but is enough to crash the `writeVideo` method which expect a _fixed_ frame size along all the movie frames. In your case you are using `getframe(fig)` on the figure, but the error is the same: the size of the captured figure frame was changed between 2 iterations of your loop. You have to _fix_ as many parameters as you can to avoid this automatic resizing.

Comment: @ Benoit_11: Yes, the aim is to capture the figure while the user f.e. orbits the plot via the camera controls...